# Silent install crashes due to Unknown Publisher. Is there a way to overcome this?

Tags: installation, chef-infra, silent-installer

I am using Chef and have managed to silently install notepad++ and even install it into the correct directory.
However, when I try to use this method for Z-Zip it crashes. I believe this is due to the warning message which can be found when I try a manual install.

```
"Do you want to allow the following program from an unknown publisher to make changes to this computer?"
```

Is there something I can do so the silent install automatically selects "yes". I have found ways of manually adding the website to be trusted etc but this defeats the purpose of a silent install.

Chef error:

```
 ERROR: Error connecting to http://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1700-x64.exe
```

The code I am using:

```
#7Zip attributes
default['7zip']['url']      = "http://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1700-x64.exe"
default['7zip']['package_name'] = "7-Zip"
default['7zip']['home']     = "D:\\Home\\Apps\\7Zip"
default['7zip']['options']  = " /S /D="+default['7zip']['home']
```

I think that I need to add something to the last line between /S and /D

And:

```
%w{ 7zip }.each do |pkg|
  package node[pkg]['package_name'] do
    source node[pkg]['url']
      installer_type :custom
    options node[pkg]['options']
    action :install
  end
end
```

Comment: I believe I can manually download the installer.exe then push it a repo. Meaning that future downloads from other users can bypass the problem I am having now

Comment: Is your server able to access the internet normally? Maybe you need to configure a proxy of some kind.